# input list from datalist how to determine the number of elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have datalist with over 800 elements, and i want to determinate number of elements which be showed.

```
<input
id="input-search"
ref ={inputRef}
list ="pokeNames"
></input>
<datalist 
id="pokeNames"
>
    {pokeNames.map((pokeName :string) => (
        <option
            key={pokeName}
        >{pokeName}
        </option>
    ))}
</datalist>
```

problem is here [image]

a number of elements is to high. on mobile devices options cover keyboard. I was looking for solution how to set amount of elements or how to set height/overflow of this

Comment: set `max-height: 400px` or any `px` you want.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `style` attribute on your datalist to `max-height: 50px` or however many pixels you want the list to be. Example:

```
<input
id="input-search"
ref ={inputRef}
list ="pokeNames"
></input>
<datalist style="max-height: 50px;"
id="pokeNames"
>
    {pokeNames.map((pokeName :string) => (
        <option
            key={pokeName}
        >{pokeName}
        </option>
    ))}
</datalist>
```

Or, in an external stylesheet, add:

```
#pokeNames{
    max-height: 50px;/*again, however many pixels you want*/
}
```

If this solved your problem please consider checking this as answer(Checkmark button).